# Things one should be aware of before deleting account?

Tags: discussion, support

I am about to delete my account (and not just stay inactive). Since I am pretty heavily addicted to the website, I fear I might have an urge to post a comment or an answer to a question (...and possible post a question?). Is it possible to do so without any account? It seems so because when I log off, the option to post an answer is available as long as I enter a username and my email address. But on the other hand I do not see any guest posting questions and answers and comments... so I am wondering whether this is really possible.

Is there any other caveat I should be aware of, before deleting my account? I understand that it's a definitive move, I will never be able to recover my account nor my points and badges. Is there more to it?

Edit: **Thanks for all, everyone.**

Signed: coniferous_smeller-something

Comment: General tip: Concerning SE addiction, consider browsing the mother meta site for advice. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4004/209806 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to clean up some of your comments that are of no lasting values, just to reduce the amount of debris left behind.

It's possible to answer without registering on the site: typing something that looks like an email address and something arbitrary for a name is enough.

However, asking questions on Physics requires registration, it's one of a few Stack Exchange sites that have this requirement.

That said, a user who posted just once (either a question or an answer) and never voted has an option to immediately delete their account just by clicking a button in profile settings. This can be used to post-and-go without leaving an account behind.

Comment: Thank you very much. About the comments, I do not care if they stay, or if they get removed. Moderators can still delete them if they want to.

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR Sure, that's true, but it helps keep the site clean if you remove your own comments (especially on questions) when they're no longer relevant. Of course there's no obligation for you to remove comments, but you'd be doing us a favor if you did.

Comment: @DavidZ Ok DavidZ, I'll consider it. I'm also reconsidering quitting (I had pushed the button but there was that 24 hours countdown and I canceled it... not sure yet what I'll do)

Comment: Sure, sounds good. It's entirely up to you whether you decide to delete your account or not, and whether you remove your comments or not. (By the way, what I said about removing comments applies even if you're not deleting your account - it's always nice to remove comments that are no longer relevant, although it's never an obligation.)